# Aligning columns without WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

I am looking for a good way to design a multi-column layout which reflows the controls in the columns according to the space available. I have a list of labels and fields which display information, and sometimes the view they are contained in needs to be tall and skinny, other times short and wide.

A simple solution is to use a `WrapPanel`:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Some label:</Label>
        <TextBlock>Some value</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Some other label:</Label>
        <TextBlock>Some bigger value</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>A:</Label>
        <TextBlock>B</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</WrapPanel>
```

I want the labels and values all to line up horizontally into columns, without specifying a static width. Right now the `Label`s and `TextBlock`s are just sized based on their content.

Comment: Did you try WrapPanel  as list's  ItemsContainer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add WrapPanel as an ItemsContainer in ListBox?

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsContainer>
    <WrapPanel />
  </ListBox.ItemsContainer>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: ListBox does not have an ItemsContainer property. Were you referring to ItemsPanel? If so, could you elaborate on your suggestion? It seems like an interesting approach.